# PyAudio Responsive Recording

Tags: python, user-interface, asynchronous, nonblocking, pyaudio

I've seen the recording tutorial on the PyAudio website for recording a fixed length recording, but I was wondering how I could do the same with a non-fixed recording? Bascially, I want to create buttons to start and end the recording but I haven't found anything on the matter. Any ideas, and I am not looking for an alternative library?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Best is to use the non-blocking way of recording, i.e. you provide a callback function that gets called from the moment you start the stream and keeps getting called for every block/buffer that gets processed until you stop the stream.

In that callback function you check for a boolean for example, and when it is true you write the incoming buffer to a datastructure, when it is false you ignore the incoming buffer. This boolean can be set from clicking a button for example.

EDIT: look at the example of wire audio: http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/#wire-callback-example
The stream is opened with an argument

```
stream_callback=my_callback
```

Where my_callback is a regular function declared as

```
def my_callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status)
```

This function will be called every time a new buffer is available. `in_data` contains the input, which you want to record. In this example, `in_data` just gets returned in a tuple together with `pyaudio.paContinue`. Which means that the incoming buffer from the input device is put/copied back into the output buffer sent the the output device (its the same device, so its actually routing input to output aka wire). See the api docs for a bit more explanation: http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/docs/#pyaudio.PyAudio.open

So in this function you can do something like (this is an extract from some code I've written, which is not complete: I use some functions not depicted. Also I play a sinewave on one channel and noise on the other in 24bit format.):

```
record_on = False
playback_on = False

recorded_frames = queue.Queue()

def callback_play_sine(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
    if record_on:
        global recorded_frames
        recorded_frames.put(in_data)

    if playback_on:
        left_channel_data = mysine.next_block(frame_count) * MAX_INT24 * gain
        right_channel_data = ((np.random.rand(frame_count) * 2) - 1) * MAX_INT24 * gain
        data = interleave_channels(max_nr_of_channels, (left_output_channel, left_channel_data), (right_output_channel, right_channel_data))
        data = convert_int32_to_24bit_bytestream(data)
    else:
        data = np.zeros(frame_count*max_nr_of_channels).tostring()

    if stop_callback:
        callback_flag = pyaudio.paComplete
    else:
        callback_flag = pyaudio.paContinue

    return data, callback_flag
```

You can then set `record_on` and `playback_on` to `True` or `False` from another part of your code while the stream is open/running, causing recording and playback to start or stop independently without interrupting the stream.
I copy the `in_data` in a (threadsafe) `queue`, which is used by another thread to write to disk there, else the queue will get big after a while.

BTW: pyaudio is based on portaudio, which has much more documentation and helpful tips. For example (http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/writing_a_callback.html): the callback function has to finish before a new buffer is presented, else buffers will be lost. So writing to a file inside the callback function usually not a good idea. (though writing to a file gets buffered and I don't know if it blocks when its written to disk eventually)

Comment: I'm not following you. Can you explain this method further?

Comment: I'm not familiar with C or C++. Can you actually explain some Python?

Comment: Can this possibly be any simpler?

Comment: As far as I know not really. You could use the non-callback (blocking) version, but then you have to put it in a separate thread if you don't want the rest of the code to freeze up, which is probably more complicated. Also the callback version is the standard way to interact with a realtime IO device. The IO device causes an interrupt in the operating system/driver which triggers some function to get called (callback), the blocking way of working is just a convenience built on top of this for the simplest of cases.

Comment: I figured out a better way using Pygame, simply add as the program updates using the normal recording program.

Comment: That's what I'm using to simulate button presses. See below.

Comment: why is `data` being returned?

Comment: @SudipBhattarai `callback_play_sine` is a function which is assigned to the 'audio thread'. This thread will execute the function when playback is started and it needs more data to play back. When the audio thread executes the function, it passes some arguments to the function (in_data and such), during the function call we calculate what should be played back, put that in data and when the function returns, the `data` buffer is captured by the audio thread and (eventually) passed on the the actual audio interface.

Comment: @EmileVrijdags it's true when we are playing from audio file. But aren't we recording? I suppose we will not use speaker while we are recording. Otherwise there will be a loopback

Comment: @SudipBhattarai That depends on your setup and/or on the application. You might be recording an external source  (e.g. a synth, sampler..), perhaps do realtime processing (even if it is just mixing multiple channels or something), and play it back again. Or in my case, I was playing back test signals that went through an external processor, which were then recorded again. That way I used python to create automated tests for a hardware integration of some dsp algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pyaudio
import wave

import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
scr = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
recording = True

CHUNK = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 5
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = "output.wav"

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                channels=CHANNELS,
                rate=RATE,
                input=True,
                frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

print("* recording")

frames = []

while True:
    if recording:
        data = stream.read(CHUNK)
        frames.append(data)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == KEYDOWN and recording:
            print("* done recording")

            stream.stop_stream()
            stream.close()
            p.terminate()

            wf = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
            wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
            wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
            wf.setframerate(RATE)
            wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
            wf.close()
            recording = False

        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit(); sys.exit()
```

Answer (score -1):

This is what I came up with when compiling it to an exe. Passing arguments to the

```
exeparser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-t', dest='time', action='store')
args = parser.parse_args()
time = int(args.time)
```