# I want to use pyaudio to record wav more than hours

Tags: python, pyaudio

I use pyaudio with python2.7.13 to record wav ,but my pragram dead when I record more than 1 hour , how can I do if I want to record for more than 1 hour with py2.7. Thanks for your replay!

Comment: For an example, have a look at [rec_unlimited.py](https://github.com/spatialaudio/python-sounddevice/blob/master/examples/rec_unlimited.py).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely you can record audio for more than an hour using pyaudio. Try invoking the recording function in a thread and put the main process in a loop or sleep for that period. 
Note: Make sure you do not run out of memory.

Comment: Thank you very much,I have invoked the recording function in a new thread out of the main loop,and use "join()" to make the main loop wait it.It worked effectively!   I will appreciate it if  you can tell me the reason of it or give me some document to read.

Comment: It is a generalized practice to do so. For a better understanding of what happens under the hood , you can refer here.
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28417733/pyaudio-responsive-recording/28418081#28418081